# How to run webdriver test in specific version of Firefox (with Python)?

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

On my machine I have Firefox 21.0 and Firefox 27.0.1 installed. 
How can I force Selenium webdriver to run test using a given version of Firefox browser?

Answer (score 5):

Specify path to firefox binary using `FirefoxBinary`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=FirefoxBinary('path goes here'))
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for an answer! I will check and let know.

Comment: And second question: is it possible to force FF 27 to bevahe like different version of FF (26 or 25)?

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately I'm getting error `'FirefoxBinary' object has no attribute 'native_events_enabled'`

Comment: I put incorrect erros message in previous comment. I'm getting `Access is denied`. Should I set something more to be able to start particular version of Firefox?

Comment: Update: problem (Access is denied) resolved, I put incorrect path (typo).

Comment: @donatelo please accept the answer if it deserves to be accepted. Thanks.